# PHP Codeigniter :How to use normal variable from one function to another function

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a function like below, I want to use $totaldays variable into calculate function

```
public function add()
{
$totaldays = 10;
}
public function calculate()
{
$result = 1000/$totaldays
}
```

Comment: Make it global (define it outside of the function) OR pass it as function argument....

Comment: Call calculate function inside add function and pass $totaldays as parameter to calculate() function

Comment: `$this` is a normal variable.

Comment: is this functions inside a class???

Comment: yes , this function inside a class

Comment: keep $totaldays as global parameter or local parameter inside calculate funtion.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way to do is to create properties.
A class may contain its variables (called "properties"), so that you cant set and access it whenever you want.

```
class maths{

    private $totaldays = 1;

    public function add()
    {
       $this->totaldays = 10;
    }
    public function calculate()
    {
        $totaldays = $this->totaldays;
        $result = 1000/$totaldays;
    }
}
```

Comment: plus1 but would need to be aware of division by 0 issue if add is not called before calculate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getter and setter methods to retrieve and set the variables

```
private $totalDays;
public function setTotalDays($days)
{
$this->totalDays= $days;
}
public function getTotalDays()
{
return $this->totalDays;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the values to the functions and return back the return value.

```
function add($x){
    $totaldays = $x;
    Return $totaldays;
 }
 function calculate($totaldays){
    $result = 1000/$totaldays;
    Return $result;
 }

 $totaldays = add(10);
 Echo calculate($totaldays); //100
```

https://3v4l.org/7Usk2